# How to handle package uninstalling with background task in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have a uwp application and I need to handle when the package is uninstalled with [PackageCatalog.PackageUninstalling Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.packagecatalog.packageuninstalling?view=winrt-19041). The problem is this event is handled only when the application is running. But when the applicatin is closed the event is not handled.
I have seen that it could be possible with Background Taks but I didn't found which appropriate trigger to set when regisetring background task.

1. Is the background task the correct method to handle this event when the application is closed?
   2.If yes how to implement it? if no, is there another method?

Answer (score 0):

> How to handle package uninstalling with background task in UWP?

I'm afraid you can't make notification when uninstall uwp app. UWP only support [run a background task when your UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-during-updatetask) app is updated. And currently there is no such task to do this. If you do want this feature please feel free post your requirement with Windows Feed Back Hub app.